# Use default incoming call screen fro making fake call

Tags: android, phone-call

Is there a way to use default incoming call screen with its functionality (answer and reject) from inside my application.
I want to make fake call from inside my application and i don't want to create custom incoming screen but use default incoming call screen on device because different devices have different incoming screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this can't be done using the standard SDK. First, the call screen activity can only be launched by the system. Second, vendor-specific skins of Android often replace the default phone app with a custom one, so it's unlikely you'd be able to do this on all devices with just a single piece of code even if it were possible.

Your best bet would be to try to recreate the incoming call screen for the most popular devices and detect which device the user is running, which I know isn't what you wanted to hear. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast response, this isn't what i wanted to hear but it how it is, I will have to manage it differently.